# Send chars with UDP

Tags: c, udp, chars

I'm trying to send text with UDP, by sending every character separately, but something seems to be wrong.
This is the client:

```
while(strcmp(sir,"0")!=0)
{
     printf("Text number %d:", i);
     i++;
     scanf("%s",sir);
     printf("\n");
     sirLen=strlen(sir);
     for(j=0;j<sirLen;j++)
     {     c=sir[j];
          printf("%c",c);
          sendto(sock, &c, sizeof(char), 0, (struct sockaddr *)&ServAddr, sizeof(ServAddr));
     }
}

raspunsLen=recvfrom(sock, raspuns, SIRMAX, 0,(struct sockaddr *) &fromAddr, &fromSize);
raspuns[raspunsLen] = '\0';
printf("%s",raspuns);
```

And this would be the server:

```
for (;;) 
{
    cliAddrLen = sizeof(ClntAddr); 
    while(sir != '0')
    { 
      recvfrom(sock, &sir, sizeof(char), 0,(struct sockaddr *) &ClntAddr, &cliAddrLen);
      raspuns[i]=sir;
      printf("%c",sir);
    }
    raspunsMsgSize=strlen(raspuns); 
    sendto(sock, raspuns, raspunsMsgSize, 0, (struct sockaddr *) &ClntAddr,             sizeof(ClntAddr));
}
```

It works when I send whole pieces of text but this way the server doesn't seem to be receiving anything. Hope someone can help.
Thank you.

Comment: One quick suggestion, never use UDP for a sending mechanism where u have individual character to be sent in a packet. Because UDP is not a reliable protocol and u will never know what comes after what. If this is the case you have to use tcp protocol.

Comment: Your code expects '0' at the end, but I don't see you sending it - unless it's a part of the string the user types in. In fact, you probably meant 0, as in "byte with all bits clear", but you don't send that either. Try typing, say, "CS 101" as your input string.

Comment: What is the declaration of `sir` in the server portion?

Comment: @maheshgupta024 I know it is unreliable,  but I have to send each character separately.Again, I know this would be something you would do using TCP, but this is how I'm requested to do it.Don't know why.School project.

Comment: @Mark Wilkins It is `char sir='1';`

Comment: @VDCan: I was mainly wondering since it was an array in the client.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect:

```
while(sir != '0')
```

should be:

```
while(sir != 0)
```

or possibly:

```
while( * sir != 0 )
```

But really, you haven't posted enough code to be sure.

Comment: I feel it is not *sir, it is a normal variable you see he has used the address of the sir variable in other calls too.. According to me it is because of the unreliable udp protocol.

Comment: I'm sorry for not posting the whole code. It would have taken to much space. As I said, the program works with sending strings, but not with characters. Maybe I'll just stick with sending strings.